# get day of datepicker and use in a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I work with asp.net mvc2,I have a table session, each session has a date determined well, I want if I select a data datepicker  the dropdownlist is filled by the sessions of this  day, I wrote a function in jquery for that, I get a build the datepicker and I select a date, but no session is displayed in the dropdownlist

Comment: Can you show us some of your code on what you have already done?

Comment: I found my problem,it's because I  use two separated function in javascript, you can ask me how to use two functions